# URL change according to site location in Liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I would like to create a website on Liferay 6.2 and would like to master a URL such as this one:

www.NomDomaine.com/web/NP/nom_page

I would just change the NP as part (city name) to display the payroll name based on the location of the site.

I created the site with the page it's still this spot to display the name of page under ISO format by exmple :  France => fr.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I assumed that you would like to have your page URL as [www.NomDomaine.com/web/NP/nom_page](http://www.NomDomaine.com/web/NP/nom_page)

To achieve this,

1. Go to Control Panel->Portal Settings,and under the **Virtual Host** Place **www.NomDomaine.com** and Save
2. Then, go to Control Panel->Sites->, then click on **Configuration**, you can find **Site Settings**, click on it and go to **Site URL**, and under the **Friendly URL**, type **/NP* and Save

Now you can access any of your site page with the URL [www.NomDomaine.com/web/NP/nom_page](http://www.NomDomaine.com/web/NP/nom_page)

Comment: for exemple I have more site visitors from more Citys, if a visitor in France visit my website to display:

www.nomdommaine.com/web/fr

if another user in Morocco visit my website to display

www.nomdommaine.com/web/fr


only the party City name (en, ma ....)  must dynamically change and that if possible on Liferay?

Comment: You can right your logic in post-login hook. If you can get city of the user, you can redirect him to that specific site page in post login hook.